# How should I set up my app settings if I want the product name to include invalid* characters?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want my app name, as the users see it, to include an exclamation mark. However, I don't want to encounter some technical problems, now or later. What's best way to set it up? Are there some hidden problems I should be aware of?

What about other options: unicode characters that don't fit into 16 bits? Emojis?

I **know**, how to set up app's bundle, product name and display name, this is not a duplicate question about these things. I'm asking about this particular scenario, because I'm afraid there are some nuances that I don't know I should ask about, and which I'll run into later.

---

- By invalid, I mean invalid in certain contexts: such as invalid in path names, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about just what appears under the icon? That has no affect on anything else.

Select your project and go to the Info tab. Go to the "Bundle display name" setting and simply set its value to whatever you want under the icon.

That's it. Use any character you want. No files or anything are related to this value.

Comment: Will it be the same in the AppStore, notifications and all the other places where the user will see the app and everything related to it? All other identifiers are seen to developer only?

Comment: There is also the app name that you provide on the  iTunes Connect website.